# Smoothness of a power of smooth non-negative function

Tags: real-analysis, smoothness

Let $f$ be a non-negative infinitely smooth function on the real line. Is it true that for any constant $\alpha$ the function $f^\alpha$ is infinitely smooth?

Comment: No. it is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $f(x)=x^2,$ while $a=1/4.$

Answer (score 4):

There is an interesting variant of the question: Suppose that the funktion is smooth, positive, and *flat* at  all zeroes  (i.e. all derivatives vanish). Is the square root again smooth?

Glaeser proved that it is continuously differebtiable and gave an example wehre it is not twice differentiable.

Comment: There is a big theory of this sort of thing, going back to Whitney, I believe.